# some PPT/PDF/DOC files got infected with wmvvhlb file extension

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

In my Pc, some ppt and doc files got infected with .wmvvhlb extension.
I googled for this .wmvvhlb file extension repair, but no results at all.

I am not able to open those files with microsoft powerpoint or word.

Even Outlook pst file got infected with the same.

Can someone please tell me what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this. Your files are encrypted my ransomware. There should be web page on your computer which ask you to pay some amount of bitcoins. But even if you pay its not sure you will get decryption key